# Merging elements that do not have direct references

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any way to transform xml1 into xml2 using XSLT 1.0?

*xml1*:

```
<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>010</ITEM_NUMBER>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>020</ITEM_NUMBER>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>

<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>010</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AD_SPEC_NO>000001</AD_SPEC_NO>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT>
<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>020</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AD_SPEC_NO>000002</AD_SPEC_NO>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT>

<E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU>
    <AD_SPEC_NO>000001</AD_SPEC_NO>
    <KEYWORD>key1</KEYWORD>
</E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU>
<E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU>
    <AD_SPEC_NO>000002</AD_SPEC_NO>
    <KEYWORD>key2</KEYWORD>
</E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU>
```

into *xml2*:

```
<Ad>
    <ad-number>010</ad-number>
    <keyword>key1</keyword>
</Ad>
<Ad>
    <ad-number>020</ad-number>
    <keyword>key2</keyword>
</Ad>
```

If there is no way to make direct transformation, it would help to merge *xml1* into something like:

```
<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>010</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <KEYWORD>key1</KEYWORD>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
<E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>020</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <KEYWORD>key2</KEYWORD>
</E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT>
```

Comment: Aleksandr Stzhalkovski: The answer you have currently accepted is not as good and precise as the best answer submitted -- the one by @TimC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of two keys to look up the data. Firstly to look up **E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT** elements by **ITEM_NUMBER**

```
<xsl:key name="ad1" match="E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT" use="ITEM_NUMBER" />
```

Then one to look up **E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU** elements by **AD_SPEC_NO**

```
<xsl:key name="ad2" match="E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU" use="AD_SPEC_NO" />
```

Then, for a given **E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT** element, you would get the **keyword** like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('ad2', key('ad1', ITEM_NUMBER)/AD_SPEC_NO)/KEYWORD" />
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="ad1" match="E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT" use="ITEM_NUMBER" />
   <xsl:key name="ad2" match="E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU" use="AD_SPEC_NO" />

   <xsl:template match="/ROOT">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT">
      <Ad>
         <ad-number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NUMBER" /></ad-number>
         <keyword><xsl:value-of select="key('ad2', key('ad1', ITEM_NUMBER)/AD_SPEC_NO)/KEYWORD" /></keyword>
      </Ad>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML (assuming a ROOT element is present), the following is output

```
<Ad>
    <ad-number>010</ad-number>
    <keyword>key1</keyword>
</Ad>
<Ad>
    <ad-number>020</ad-number>
    <keyword>key2</keyword>
</Ad>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion, cause I can't make any test now.

Use a key to get your AD_SPEC_NO by ITEM_NUMBER:

```
  <xsl:key name="AD_SPEC_NO" match="E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_AD_OUT" use="ITEM_NUMBER"/>
```

Then, for example, in a template matching E1BPBUSISM008_ITEM_OUT, you can use the following expression to get the related keyword value:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::E1BPBUSISM008_AD_SPEC_AD_OU[
       AD_SPEC_NO = key('AD_SPEC_NO',current()/ITEM_NUMBER)/AD_SPEC_NO]
       /KEYWORD" />
```